# zk - disable key controls for combobox

Tags: combobox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, zk

Is it possible to disable the keyboard controls for a [Combobox](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Input/Combobox#Mouseless_Entry_Combobox) in ZK?

That is, when a user enters some text into a Combobox, by default they can use the arrow keys to move up and down the list. I would like to disable this functionally as it doesn't work well with the user experience we are designing.

I see nothing in the documentation explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override _doKeyDown js function,

e.g.,

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">
    <combobox>
        <attribute w:name="_doKeyDown"><![CDATA[
            function (evt) {
                var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
                if (keyCode != 38 && keyCode != 40) {
                    this.$_doKeyDown(evt);
                }
            }
        ]]></attribute>
        <comboitem label="item one" />
        <comboitem label="item two" />
        <comboitem label="item three" />
    </combobox>
</zk>
```

Comment: Darn, really wanted a simple config approach but it seems like this is it =\

Comment: true, I also thought this should be a feature (like ignoredKeycode="38,40" or something similar to this)