# Disable default behaviour for the keystrokes that listbox responds in zk

Tags: zk

Lisbox in zk by default answers keystrokes like page up and page down, up and down keys and home and end keys. Ex: I want the currently selected row to come down when user hits down arrow. I gave all above keys in `ctrlKeys` attribute, to call the back-end bean when specific keys are hit. But it doesn't call for above keys. It calls back end bean for keys like "delete". I want to disable the default behavior for above keys for listbox in zk. Kindly help me. This is the `ctrlKeys` attribute I gave,

```
ctrlKeys="#home#end#del#up#down#pgup#pgdn" 

onCtrlKey="@command('answerKeyStroke',keyCode=event.getKeyCode(), id=0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15947733/zk-disable-key-controls-for-combobox)

From that answer, this is the solution (just this is a combobox in stead of a listbox)

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">
    <combobox>
        <attribute w:name="_doKeyDown"><![CDATA[
            function (evt) {
                var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
                if (keyCode != 38 && keyCode != 40) {
                    this.$_doKeyDown(evt);
                }
            }
        ]]></attribute>
        <comboitem label="item one" />
        <comboitem label="item two" />
        <comboitem label="item three" />
    </combobox>
</zk>
```